# Approximation method of moments (delta) method - worked out example

Tags: statistics, taylor-expansion, approximation, moment-generating-functions, error-propagation

I am self-studying the delta method, but i cannot understand it. Here i provide an worked out example from Rice in hos book "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis".

[image]

**How are the calculations obtained?**

Comment: Do you have any particular question or you are interested in brief presentation of the Delta method (where in this case I'm not sure that you will get a better answer then In your book)?

Comment: I counldnt figure out the calculations, but meanwhile i know where the problem was and solveed them. In short, $$ E(g(x)) \text{is not equal to} g(x)E(x) $$